# Save complete tf.keras model without custom objects?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, restore

Let's suppose we have some model including custom losses & metrics that are important during training. Is it possible to save the complete model, so weights + graphdef / pb-file, without the custom objects?

During inference the custom losses & metrics are **not needed**, thus...

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("some_model", custom_objects={...})
```

...would just render the inference code more complicated since custom object code needs to be included for inferencing (although it is not used).

However, `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint` (even with `include_optimizer=False`) as well as calling `model.save()` always save the model definition *including* the custom objects.

Hence, simply loading the model with...

```
tf.keras.models.load_model("some_model")
```

...will always fail and complain about the missing custom objects.

Is it possible to somehow save the whole model without custom losses/metrics? To get an "inference" version of the network that is easy to load?

Or is the only solution to this to freeze everything to a TFLite model?

Of course, one could simply use `model.save_weights()`, but then the actual code needs to be included for inference later, which is not desired.

Answer (score 10):

If the purpose is to prevent the loading of loss and metrics, you can use the parameter `compile` in `load_model`:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("some_model", compile=False)
```

This should skip the requirement of loss and metrics/optimizers since the model is not compiled. Of course you cannot train the model now, but it should work fine for inference using `model.predict()`

Comment: what if you want to train it again from where you left ?